# C#/WPF UserControl binding in unreferenced assembly

Tags: wpf, dll, binding, user-controls

I have a User Control Library that I am loading dynamically.  From that lib I am inserting a Tabitem into a TabControl.  I can load the tab and show it without error.  However, I can't seem to get the binding on the control working.

This is the code I use to load it and add it to the TabControl:

```
    Assembly moduleAssembly = Assembly.Load("ControlLib");            
    UserControl uc = (UserControl)Application.LoadComponent(new System.Uri("/ControlLib;component/UserControl1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    TabControl itemsTab = (TabControl)this.FindName("mainTabControl");
    TabItem newTab = new TabItem();
    newTab.Content = uc;
    newTab.Header = "Test";
    itemsTab.Items.Add(newTab);
    itemsTab.SelectedItem = newTab;
```

This is the C# code for the control:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{        
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestStringProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestString", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

    public string TestString { get; set; }

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TestString = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

This is the XAML code for the control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControlLib.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>        
        <TextBox Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding Path=TestString, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When the tab displays all I see if a blank in the TextBox rather than "Hello World"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would still be setting the DataContext of your user control to instance of the class. Just how you go about creating that instance differs as you would be loading that dll a runtime. But fundamentally the binding setup remains the same.

```
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"yourdllname.dll");
    Type type = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.SampleViewModel"); 
    object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    DataContext = instanceOfMyType;
```

For how basic databinding works read MSDN  [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Make sure you select the correct framework on the top of the screen.

EDIT

Usually this is created as a separate class (ViewModel in MVVM pattern).

```
 public partial class Window3 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Window3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
            TestString = "Hello World.";
        }

        string _testString;
        ///<summary>Gets or sets TestString.</summary>            
        public string TestString
        {
            get { return _testString; }
            set { _testString = value; OnPropertyChanged("TestString"); }
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I set the DataContext to the UC won’t that assign the DataContext for the entire app?  I need it just for the tab in question.  I tried setting the tab item datacontext to the UC and I also tried just setting the entire DataContext to the UC, neither worked.  I updated the code to show the exact code I’m using… yours was a bit different so I tried it.  I get the same results either way… items show but binding is failing.  I feel like I’m missing some ‘little’ thing…

Comment: see EDIT. Setting the datacontext to UC will not assign the datacontext for the entire app. It is inherited by elements in visual tree. Unless I am missing something in your requirement, a dependency property is not needed here.

Comment: Thanks SKG! That fixed my problem... I didn't need the DP and I totally misunderstood the DataContext in the UC.  I REALLY appreciate your help!